# Ffmpeg blur part of video interacively

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to blur part of live stream conditionally in realtime with ffmpeg.
I read about `zeromq` filter, but the output of `ffmpeg -filters` says that `boxblur` filter doesn't support commands. For example, I want to blur the bottom half of the video then after some time disable blur then blur all video.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is the timing arbitrary, or do you have predetermined times in the duration you want to apply the blur?

Comment: @llogan timing is arbitrary, but rectangles are known. Blur should be enabled and disabled by python script through sending commands to ffmpeg

Comment: overlay and crop support commands, so one method could be to blur the whole input, then use crop to select desired area, and overlay it over the non-blurred input. See [Apply blur over face](https://superuser.com/a/901705/) for a basic, non-command example.

Comment: avgblur, gblur, and yaepblur all have command support.

Comment: A third option is to submit a patch to enable command support in your favorite blur filter, or offer a bounty for a developer to add command support via a feature request on the bug tracker.